# Write the previous value into the variable

Tags: javascript

I have the drag function.

```
function drag(ev) {

// if not dragging
if (!isDragging) {
    isDragging = true;
}

// position
var position = ev.deltaY;

control.style.transform = 'translateY(' + position + 'px)';
control.style.transition = 'none';

console.log(position);
}
```

When I drag an element it moves according to deltaY. How can I memorize the position so that each time there is a position + savePosition from the previous drag. (var savePosition = ?) Thank you!

Comment: You can define savePosition outside of your function and set ```savePosition = ev.deltaY;``` inside your function.

Comment: or you can get the current translated Y value then add the delta to it

Comment: @Huangism you mean savePosition = position + ev.deltaY? It's not working.

Comment: You can either save the position of the last drag (define the savedPosition var outside of your function so you can use it then update it OR you can get the current translated Y of your element then add the delta to it. Your comment doesn't make sense for any of those 2 solutions. Saving position is the easier way to go

Comment: @Huangism Can you help with the second variant? The first one doesn't suit me because I use hammer js. And I can only define delta in function.

Answer (score 0):

I made this decision.

```
function drag(ev) {

// if not dragging
if (!isDragging) {
    isDragging = true;
}

// position
var position = ev.deltaY + savePosition;

control.style.transform = 'translateY(' + position + 'px)';
control.style.transition = 'none';

// dropped
if (ev.isFinal) {
    isDragging = false;
    savePosition = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `savePosition` might be a global variable and also you have an extra `}` in `if (ev.isFinal) {`